# erand48(X) not working in C++ , Visual Studio 12

Tags: c++

I have C++ code which has a line with `erand48(X)` in few lines and Visual Studio gives `Unable to identify` error on this. I searched online and found out that `erand48()` does not exist in Visual Studio (or in Windows). Suggestions were to write the implementation by oneself. Can anyone provide me the implementation for this as I am new to this and I am short at time to give too much of time to this.

Also there are few line which starts with `uniform` like `uniform sampler2D Texture` and it gives error as `the value or constructor 'uniform' not defined`. Why is it showing this error and how to remove this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`uniform_real_distribution`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee462299.aspx) Class as instead.

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
std:: default_random_engine generator;
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distr(0.0,1.0);
double erand48(int X){
    return distr(generator);
}

int main(){
    std::cout << erand48(1) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

or just use [`LibGW32C for windows`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libgw32c.htm)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Yuck This is perfectly valid as an answer: It says what to use, and then provides documentation on it.

Comment: @Pokechu22 One of many in the low quality queue. As an answer this needs more work. Not my downvote, by the way.

Comment: @Yuck What else should I add to this answer in order to achieve a perfect answer? Should i copy the code from the MSDN page or somehing else? I'm still new to stackoverflow, even a link to a guide or somthing may really do great help.

Comment: Li Ke thanks a lot for the help! @Pokechu22 & @Yuck thanks for your help also. But the first and the major part of my post was regarding `erand48`. Can you provide answer to that?

Comment: @user2966197 answer edited. You may have a try. This erand48() may generate a  uniform random float number for your program but I have to remind you there remains difference between two erand48().

Comment: @user2966197 or you can simply use LibGW32C for Windows.[link](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libgw32c.htm)

Comment: @LiKe how do I use LibGW32C in visual studio? Also Which file should I use as in the downloaded file from above link there are multiple .h and other files?

Comment: @user2966197 If you simply want to make it work quick but dirty, just download the src zip pack and include everything you need. If you want to make it work but not that dirty, download the developer zip pack and add the lib path to the setting of your compiler. If you want to make it work and also keep your settings clean, you may read the src and   copy every file you need.(don't forget the license) here is the [installation guide](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/install.html).

Comment: @LiKe I meant that there are so many folders with so many .h files that I am unable to understand which one should I include for `errand48`

Comment: @user2966197 add lib to your compile settings and according to this [page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/drand48.html) you should #include<stdlib.h> before you use erand48()

Comment: @LiKe I apologise for not being able to understand but which 'lib' should I add to my compile settings? Theres is no file in the downloaded files(which are so many) with the name lib

Comment: @user2966197 1.Extract the pack libgw32c-0.4-lib.zip 2.add the path of "lib" folder to your compiler's library path setting and add the path of "include" folder to your compiler's include path setting 3. then use the code as if you are under linux.

Comment: @LiKe there is no lib folder in the extracted files

Comment: @user2966197 Just rename libgw32c.a to libgw32c.lib and use this in VC++.

Comment: @user2966197 how could the problem be so hard? if it doesnt work, use minGW. if it doesnt work too, use virtual machine

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for this `erand48` method as well (with Visual Studio 2015) because

1. it is thread safe,
2. caller must keep and pass the state,
3. it is pure C (don't ask me which version, it is old enough for me).

So instead of providing a (C++) alternative, I will answer the question by providing a possible implementation itself.

```
#pragma once

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define RAND48_SEED_0   (0x330e)
#define RAND48_SEED_1   (0xabcd)
#define RAND48_SEED_2   (0x1234)
#define RAND48_MULT_0   (0xe66d)
#define RAND48_MULT_1   (0xdeec)
#define RAND48_MULT_2   (0x0005)
#define RAND48_ADD      (0x000b)

unsigned short _rand48_seed[3] = {
    RAND48_SEED_0,
    RAND48_SEED_1,
    RAND48_SEED_2
};
unsigned short _rand48_mult[3] = {
    RAND48_MULT_0,
    RAND48_MULT_1,
    RAND48_MULT_2
};
unsigned short _rand48_add = RAND48_ADD;

void _dorand48(unsigned short xseed[3]) 
{
    unsigned long accu;
    unsigned short temp[2];

    accu = (unsigned long)_rand48_mult[0] * (unsigned long)xseed[0] +
        (unsigned long)_rand48_add;
    temp[0] = (unsigned short)accu;        /* lower 16 bits */
    accu >>= sizeof(unsigned short) * 8;
    accu += (unsigned long)_rand48_mult[0] * (unsigned long)xseed[1] +
        (unsigned long)_rand48_mult[1] * (unsigned long)xseed[0];
    temp[1] = (unsigned short)accu;        /* middle 16 bits */
    accu >>= sizeof(unsigned short) * 8;
    accu += _rand48_mult[0] * xseed[2] + _rand48_mult[1] * xseed[1] + _rand48_mult[2] * xseed[0];
    xseed[0] = temp[0];
    xseed[1] = temp[1];
    xseed[2] = (unsigned short)accu;
}

double erand48(unsigned short xseed[3])
{
    _dorand48(xseed);
    return ldexp((double)xseed[0], -48) +
        ldexp((double)xseed[1], -32) +
        ldexp((double)xseed[2], -16);
}

double drand48(void)
{
    return erand48(_rand48_seed);
}

long lrand48(void) 
{
    _dorand48(_rand48_seed);
    return ((long)_rand48_seed[2] << 15) + ((long)_rand48_seed[1] >> 1);
}

long nrand48(unsigned short xseed[3]) 
{
    _dorand48(xseed);
    return ((long)xseed[2] << 15) + ((long)xseed[1] >> 1);
}

long mrand48(void) 
{
    _dorand48(_rand48_seed);
    return ((long)_rand48_seed[2] << 16) + (long)_rand48_seed[1];
}

long jrand48(unsigned short xseed[3]) 
{
    _dorand48(xseed);
    return ((long)xseed[2] << 16) + (long)xseed[1];
}

void srand48(long seed) 
{
    _rand48_seed[0] = RAND48_SEED_0;
    _rand48_seed[1] = (unsigned short)seed;
    _rand48_seed[2] = (unsigned short)(seed >> 16);
    _rand48_mult[0] = RAND48_MULT_0;
    _rand48_mult[1] = RAND48_MULT_1;
    _rand48_mult[2] = RAND48_MULT_2;
    _rand48_add = RAND48_ADD;
}

unsigned short *seed48(unsigned short xseed[3]) 
{
    static unsigned short sseed[3];

    sseed[0] = _rand48_seed[0];
    sseed[1] = _rand48_seed[1];
    sseed[2] = _rand48_seed[2];
    _rand48_seed[0] = xseed[0];
    _rand48_seed[1] = xseed[1];
    _rand48_seed[2] = xseed[2];
    _rand48_mult[0] = RAND48_MULT_0;
    _rand48_mult[1] = RAND48_MULT_1;
    _rand48_mult[2] = RAND48_MULT_2;
    _rand48_add = RAND48_ADD;
    return sseed;
}

void lcong48(unsigned short p[7]) 
{
    _rand48_seed[0] = p[0];
    _rand48_seed[1] = p[1];
    _rand48_seed[2] = p[2];
    _rand48_mult[0] = p[3];
    _rand48_mult[1] = p[4];
    _rand48_mult[2] = p[5];
    _rand48_add = p[6];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"uniform sampler2D Texture" sounds like GLSL code, which is OpenGL shader code, rather than C++. If your file is actually C++, I guess the line containing "uniform sampler2D" should be part of a shader source string.